# How do I configure sysflow to send JSON event to Splunk

Tags: json, splunk, syslog

I'm new to SysFlow, and I want to send the events to Splunk.

The problem is that the events arrive at Splunk with a metadata prefix so Splunk doesn't know how to interpret the event as JSON automatically.

Here is the raw event:

```
Mar  9 21:57:26 10.0.0.158 1 2023-03-09T23:57:26+02:00 RHEL-Server /usr/bin/sfprocessor 60594 sysflow - {"version":5,"endts":0,"opflags":["EXEC"],"ret":0,"ts":1678399046064475870,"type":"PE","meta":{"schema":4,"tracename":"."},"node":{"id":"RHEL-Server","ip":"10.0.0.158"},"pproc":{"args":"--switched-root --system --deserialize 30","cmdline":"/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 30","createts":1678395155396715155,"entry":true,"exe":"/usr/lib/systemd/systemd","gid":0,"group":"root","name":"systemd","oid":"d2e72642fc1d9df2","pid":1,"tty":false,"uid":0,"user":"root"},"proc":{"acmdline":["/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 30","/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 30"],"aexe":["/usr/lib/systemd/systemd","/usr/lib/systemd/systemd"],"aname":["systemd","systemd"],"apid":[73232,1],"args":"/usr/bin/dnf makecache --timer","cmdline":"/usr/bin/dnf /usr/bin/dnf makecache --timer","createts":1678399046062638027,"entry":false,"exe":"/usr/bin/dnf","gid":0,"group":"root","name":"dnf","oid":"6a55582e3bbddc8a","pid":73232,"tid":73232,"tty":false,"uid":0,"user":"root"},"policies":[{"id":"Unauthorized installer detected","desc":"Use of package installer detected in container","priority":1},{"id":"Unauthorized installer detected","desc":"Use of package installer detected in container","priority":1}],"tags":["actionable-offense","suspicious-process","mitre:T1072"]}
```

Here is my configuration (`/etc/sysflow/pipelines/pipeline.local.json`):

```
{
  "pipeline":[
    {
     "processor": "sysflowreader",
     "handler": "flattener",
     "in": "sysflow sysflowchan",
     "out": "flat flattenerchan"
    },
    {
     "processor": "policyengine",
     "in": "flat flattenerchan",
     "out": "evt eventchan",
     "policies": "/etc/sysflow/policies/runtimeintegrity",
     "mode": "alert"
    },
    {
     "processor": "exporter",
     "in": "evt eventchan",
     "export": "syslog",
     "format": "json",
     "syslog.proto": "udp",
     "syslog.tag": "sysflow",
     "syslog.host": "splunk-server",
     "syslog.port": "514"
    }
  ]
}
```

I read SysFlow documentation about configuration [(here)](https://sysflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/processor.html#configuration)

I know how to parse the event with SPL, I just need to build an add-on that will that for me (I need the data in data models), here is the SPL:

```
index="sysflow" sourcetype="sysflow:syslog"
| rex field=_raw "^(?:[^ \n]* ){7}(?P<json>.+)"
| spath input=json
```

Comment: Are you asking how to send JSON to Splunk? Or how to send JSON to a syslog collector, and then process syslog *as if* it were JSON?

Comment: @warren I'm asking how to do it specificaly for SysFlow (I can't add this tag because I don't have enough reputation).

Comment: @warren I don't mind if it will go to a syslog collector before Splunk, I just need to remove the prefix from the event - then Splunk will parse it automatically

Comment: If you submit directly to HEC, there is no "prefix". If you're stopping with an intermediary, such as syslog-ng, you'l need to do more processing via props.conf/transforms.conf. Is there a reason you cannot submit directly to HEC?

Comment: @warren sysflow (the security tool which creates the events) doesn't have an option to send HEC requests (only syslog / local file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution... but it works

I created a Field Extraction in `props.conf`:

```
EXTRACT-json = ^(?:[^ \n]* ){7}(?P<json>.+)
```

And then parsed personally each field using the `spath()` function in `eval`, for example:

```
EVAL-file_path = spath(json, "file.path")
EVAL-parent_process = spath(json, "pproc.cmdline")
EVAL-process = spath(json, "proc.cmdline")
EVAL-user = spath(json, "proc.user")
EVAL-type = spath(json, "type")
EVAL-file_name = spath(json, "file.name")
EVAL-process_name = spath(json, "proc.name")
EVAL-parent_process_name = spath(json, "pproc.name")
EVAL-parent_process_path = spath(json, "pproc.exe")
EVAL-dest = spath(json, "node.id")
EVAL-signature = spath(json, "policies{}.id")
EVAL-file_acl = spath(json, "file.openflags{}")
EVAL-action = spath(json, "opflags{}")
```

I'm working now on an Add-On for splunkbase (CIM compliant)